# I cannot go through ng serve

Tags: angular

Whenever I type `ng serve` it prints:

> Your global Angular CLI version (10.0.1) is greater than your local
> version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use `ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false`.

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:210:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:52:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (d:\문현주\Desktop\Coursera Bootstrap\Angular\conFusion\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:77:26)
```

Does anyone know how to fix them?

Comment: Which of the two issues do you want help with? The version mismatch, or the required property issue?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three options to fix the version mismatch:

- Install the same Angular version as global Angular CLI using `npm i -g @angular/cli@6.9.2` (only recommended if this is your only Angular project)
- Update the project to the global cli's version
- Suppress the warning as instructed. If `ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false` does not work for you, you can manually turn off the warning by adding the setting to the end of your project's `angular.json`:

```
     "defaultProject": "my-awesome-project",
+    "cli": {
+      "warnings": {
+        "versionMismatch": false
+      }
+    }
   }
```